# Check if the 2 users are opening the chat at the same time

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I'm trying to check if the 2 users are opening the chat with each other. The code used to work but when I added a feature it doesn't work anymore.

This is the code:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection(getString(R.string.app_name)).document("App Collections")
                .collection("Users").document(contactID).collection("Chats With").document(userID).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                boolean chatOpened = documentSnapshot.getBoolean("chat opened");

                if (!chatOpened) {
                    firebaseFirestore.collection(getString(R.string.app_name)).document("App Collections")
                            .collection("Users").document(contactID).collection("Chats With").document(userID)
                            .update("chat opened", false);
                } else if (chatOpened) {
                    firebaseFirestore.collection(getString(R.string.app_name)).document("App Collections")
                            .collection("Users").document(contactID).collection("Chats With").document(userID)
                            .update("chat opened", true);
                }

            }
        });
```

If the current user (userID) has opened the chat and the chat user (contactID) has already opened it too, so the two are opening the chat at the same time, the "chat opened" field in the the contactID document should stay true. What is going on is that it changes to false.

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWdD8.png)

How can I check if the 2 users are opening the chat at the same time?

Comment: You are monitoring the same node as you are updating. Doesn't this cause an infinite loop of `false` updates?

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Beside that, please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry. I've updated the question. And for the playlist that you have provided, it is written in kotlin. I am a java guy.

Comment: @Blundell I don't know how to do it. But somehow this code was woking before.